# About \psplot and domain of functions

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I would like to know if i really have to calculate the domain of functions like `sqrt(x-7)` and `log(x-7)/log(2)` and tell to \psplot to work only inside that interval, e.g., for the interval `[6,16]` and functions above for example, i'm getting error from ghostscript. But not for the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\def\azul{\color{Cerulean}}
\def\cinza{\color{gray}}

\psset{xunit=0.25cm,yunit=0.5cm,linecolor=Cerulean}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4.3)(20,4.4)
  \psaxes[Dx=7,
          Dy=3,
          labelFontSize=\azul,
          tickcolor=Cerulean]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-3.7)(18.2,3.9)

  \psplot[algebraic,
          plotpoints=500,
          linecolor=blue,
          linewidth=1.5pt,
          yMinValue=-10,
          yMaxValue=10]{7.1}{16}{(log(x-7))/(log(2))}

  \psplot[algebraic,
          plotpoints=500,
          linecolor=green,
          linewidth=1.5pt,
          yMaxValue=5]{7.1}{16}{sqrt(x-7)}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I ask because we can have a lot of work with complicated functions.

Comment: I think you have to, unless (perhaps) you know the postscript language and  insert directly postscript code in your pstricks commands.

Comment: In these cases you can use `Log` and `Sqrt` functions, which check if their operand is valid. If not, they return 0. So when you're outside of the definition domain you get 0 as function value, but at least you don't get a Postscript error from ghostscript.

Comment: Very nice Christoph! With {6}{30}{(Log(x-7))/(Log(2))} i don't get any errors! But now i'm confuse, because i'm using algebraic option and on page 14 of pst-plot doc it says that Log is a Postscript function. So i can mix algebraic with Postscript functions? I need to understand that for my thesis. Any suggestion where to get more info about it? Also i need to know all the Postscript functions that i can mix with algebraic option.

Comment: Well, in the end, every function you put in is Postscript, `log` or `Log`. I think you misunderstood the part in the manual. That isn't a special emphasis on the one being a PS function and the other not. Both are PS functions. I don't know what is allowed an what not. I must have a deeper look at the code before ;) Haven't looked at it for a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot automatically determine the domain of arbitrary functions you plot. In some cases you can use special functions (in your case `Log` and `Sqrt`), which check the validity of their operand and return 0 otherwise. So, the plot isn't necessarily correct on all parts of the plot, but at least you don't get a Postscript error and you can check and correct the used domains for the respective functions.

With the `algebraic` option you can basically use any Postscript procedure which takes one number as input and evaluates to a number. As example, instead of using `Log(x-7)/log(2)` you can define your own function `Foobar` as follows:

```
\pstVerb{%
    tx@AddMathFunc begin % here is where the procedure must be defined
        /Foobar { Log 2 Log div } def
    end }%
```

As full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.25cm,yunit=0.5cm,linecolor=Cerulean}
\pstVerb{%
  tx@AddMathFunc begin
   /Foobar { Log 2 Log div } def
  end
}%
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4.3)(20,4.4)
  \psaxes[Dx=7,
          Dy=3,
          tickcolor=Cerulean]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-3.7)(18.2,3.9)

  \psplot[algebraic,
          plotpoints=500,
          linecolor=blue,
          linewidth=1.5pt,
          yMinValue=-10,
          yMaxValue=10]{6}{16}{(Log(x-7))/(log(2))}

  \psplot[algebraic,
          plotpoints=500,
          linecolor=green,
          linestyle=dotted,
          linewidth=1.5pt,
          yMaxValue=5]{6}{16}{Foobar(x-7)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So it is quite difficult to give a full list of possible functions, especially when taking into account the functions defined by various packages like `pst-func`, `pst-math`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Christoph. I see what you mean about "some problems". For example, there's something wrong with vertical balance, even with `yMaxValue` and `yMinValue` settings, in the graph below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\def\azul{\color{Cerulean}}
\def\cinza{\color{gray}}
\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm,linecolor=Cerulean}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-6.7)(9,6.8)

  \psaxes[Dy=4,
          labelFontSize=\azul,
          tickcolor=Cerulean,
          labels=y,
          ticks=y]{->}(0,0)(-6.5,-5.9)(6.9,5.95)

  \psplot[algebraic,
          plotpoints=500,
          linecolor=gray,
          linewidth=1.5pt,
          yMaxValue=5.4,
          yMinValue=-5.4]{-6}{6}{5/(6-x^2)}

  \psset{linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.5pt}
  \psline(-2.45,-5.38)(-2.45,5.8)
  \psline(2.45,-6)(2.45,5.3)
  \psline(-6,-5.4)(6,-5.4)
  \psline(-6,5.4)(6,5.4)
  \rput[B]{0}(-0.81,-1.17){\azul 0}
  \rput[B]{0}(-3.7,0.6){$\azul -\sqrt{6}$}
  \rput[B]{0}(3.2,0.6){$\azul \sqrt{6}$}
  \rput[B]{0}(6.7,-1){$\azul x$}
  \rput{0}(-0.7,5.65){$\azul y$}
  \rput(5.6,3){$\displaystyle \cinza f(x)=\frac{5}{6-x^2}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
      plotpoints=5000,
```

or more, eg 10000